powershell, enum with synonyms, string representation
I define the following enum
enum units {
    
    byte        = 1
    B           = 1
    
    Kilobyte    = 1KB
    KB          = 1KB
    
    megabyte    = 1MB
    MB          = 1MB
    
    gigabyte    = 1GB
    GB          = 1GB
}

[units].GetEnumNames() gives expected results
[units].GetEnumNames()

byte
B
Kilobyte
KB
megabyte
MB
gigabyte
GB

[units].GetEnumValues() does not
[units].GetEnumValues()

B
B
KB
KB
MB
MB
gigabyte
gigabyte

values are return with their last name, but not gigabytes which uses the first
calling .toString() gives even weirder results.
[units]::kb.tostring('f')
KB

[units]::kb.tostring('g')
KB

[units]::gb.tostring('f')
GB

[units]::gb.tostring('g')
gigabyte

is there a way to control which [string] representation will be used for enum values in case of synonym?
context
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.4046
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.4046
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


The name PowerShell returns for synonym values isn't deterministic. or so say the docs.

@sirtao thanks. it seems that I missed that line reading the doc.

You can convert an enum to Hashtable, OrderedHash, PsCustomObject or ObjectArray with below helper function.
Using your enum as example, you can do this:
function ConvertFrom-Enum {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [type]$Type,

        [ValidateSet('Hashtable', 'OrderedHash', 'PSCustomObject', 'ObjectArray')]
        [string]$As = 'OrderedHash'
    )

    if (!$Type.IsEnum) {
        Write-Warning "Type '$Type' is not an enum"
        return
    }
    if ($As -eq 'Hashtable') { $hash = @{} } else { $hash = [ordered]@{} }

    [enum]::GetNames($Type) | ForEach-Object {
        $value = Invoke-Expression -Command "([$Type]::$($_)).value__"
        if ($As -eq 'ObjectArray') { [PsCustomObject] @{'Name' = $_; 'Value' = $value } }
        else { $hash[$_] = $value }
    }

    switch ($As) {
        'ObjectArray'    { return }
        'PSCustomObject' { [PsCustomObject]$hash }
        default          { $hash }
    }
}

enum units {
    byte        = 1
    B           = 1
    Kilobyte    = 1KB
    KB          = 1KB
    megabyte    = 1MB
    MB          = 1MB
    gigabyte    = 1GB
    GB          = 1GB
}

$result = ConvertFrom-Enum -Type 'units' -As PSCustomObject

$result will now be a PsCustomObject:
byte     : 1
B        : 1
Kilobyte : 1024
KB       : 1024
megabyte : 1048576
MB       : 1048576
gigabyte : 1073741824
GB       : 1073741824

$result.GB will return 1073741824 and so does $result.gigabyte etc.
